# How to echo fetched array data from a mysql database in custom order?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been trying to print out data from a database table in custom order like for example..
I have a table and that have alot rows and have one column as listing_type which have values like Gold,Premium,Silver,Free etc for each row..! so how I would be able to print the data from fetched array in order like at first it should echo all Gold and then Premium and then Silver and then Free etc like..!

Any help would be appreciated..Thanks waiting for your reply.!

Comment: Use an `order by` clause in your sql query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `ORDER BY` clause in your `MySQL` query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
ORDER BY FIELD(`listing_type`, 'Gold', 'Premium', 'Silver', 'Free')
```

The `MySQL` function [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field) returns the position of `str` in the given strings. With this, you can create a custom order to sort your results on.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql query you can easily order results by using `field()` function,so returned results will be ordered in way where listing_type is gold first then premium then silver results then free

```
select * 
from your_table
order by field(listing_type,'Gold','premium','Silver','Free' )
```